# How to force a WebPart appears in all pages of a portal in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-parts, personalization

I'm working on a portal/CMS project and (unfortunately) build the foundation on WebParts platform.

However I need to provide an option for admin to choose whether a webpart should be display in all pages or not. Finally I've found [a nice article](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/web-parts-in-asp.net-2.0/) from *Damon Armstrong* that describes a way to store all personalization data of a group of pages into one record. Thus every changes the admin made for a webpart, affect whole pages.

But it doesn't seems to be a solution for me because of these reasons:

1- The above solution works for a group of pages; in fact we can select which pages to display all webparts, but we expect reverse: select which webpart to display in all pages.

2- After some data entry and adding webparts on pages, we'll face an issue about massive data size of personalization record that should be serialize and deserialize to display contents of each page.

May be it would be solved by writing another custom personalization provider or some hacking on webparts system, but I don't now how.
Any Ideas about the problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Could you use a master page that always loads certain web parts into a particular zone, and which prevents the user from removing them from the zone?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, But as described in the article I'm talking about, master pages doesn't solve any problem because of personalization system store its data depends on single pages not the master page.

Comment: @Mehdi: you should update your question with this information.

Comment: Ok, I've forget to describe my reasons to decline the solution in that article. I've edit the question.